# Extract a string field from list

Tags: c#

```
public class StudentLibrary
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }
}
```

List contails student library

```
List<StudentLibrary> StudentInfo;
```

Can you help me extracting student status from list. Hope I make sense.

Thank you in advance

Comment: The status of which student in the list?

Comment: _"Hope I make sense."_ Nope. _What_ student to you want to find? Have you tried to use a loop? What problem did you have?

Comment: @MarcGravell student with Max(statusID)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a particular student in mind, and you know their ID:

```
var status = StudentInfo.Where(x => x.ID == studentId)
                        .Select(x => x.Status)
                        .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: `Where` is redundant here, just put the lambda in `FirstOrDefault` and access the status property.

Comment: True, but this also risks `status` being null, so at some point, you're (presumably) going to have a null check in your code.

Comment: in where clause if i want Max(studentID) ???

Comment: Do appologies @GrantWinney your query helped me but I just realised I further need to filter above query with Max(StudentID).

Answer (score 2):

Status is integer, but it does not matter - for extracting you can use LINQ projection operator `Enumerable.Select`:

```
var statuses = StudentInfo.Select(s => s.Status);
```

If you want to concatenate all statuses in one string, then `String.Join` can help you:

```
var result = String.Join(",",  StudentInfo.Select(s => s.Status));
```

UPDATE: If you want to select student with max status:

```
var student = StudentInfo.OrderByDescending(s => s.Status).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

Two steps:

- find the student you want
- access the member you want

For example:

```
var status = list[4].Status;
//...
```

Or:

```
var student = list.Find(x => x.ID == id);
if(student != null) {
    var status = student.Status;
    //...
}
```

Note that the latter would be better served by a `Dictionary<int,Student>`; then you can do:

```
StudentLibrary student;
if(lookup.TryGetValue(id, out student)) {
    var status = student.Status;
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Var status = StudentInfo.Select(x=>x.Status)
```